# Span with 2 lines inside flex anchor only take content width

Tags: css

I have a 2-line span inside an anchor tag. The anchor tag is using `display:inline-flex;` I would like for the width of the span to take the content width rather than the width of the anchor but I can't seem to get it to work.

```css
a {
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:167px;
  height:75px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid black;
}

span {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>consectetur adipiscing elit suspendisse</span></a>
```

The desired result would be for the red background to start and end right at the sides of the first and last word on the first line like this:

[image]

Comment: you cannot ....

Comment: If add another `span` to the `span`, then it can be done!